# Fetching all users from mongo returns empty object React Meteor

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I want to create a table to display all my users. I use the `account-ui` package of Meteor to create new users.

However, It simply returns an empty object when I call my users in my React component.
Is there something I forgot ? like an import maybe ?

`imports/api/users.js` is used to Publish:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('users', function() {
        return Meteor.users.find({});
    })
}
```

then I call my component and make use of `withTracker` in which I subscribe:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class CollectionTable extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <table className="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.users.map(u => {
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{u._id}</th>
            <td>{u.profile.firstname}</td>
            <td>{u.profile.lastname}</td>
            <td>{u.profile.phonenumber}</td>
          </tr>
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('users');
  return {
    users: Meteor.users.find().fetch()
  };
})(CollectionTable);
```

Comment: Did you import the `users.js` file in your `server/main.js` ?

Comment: hi @Jankapunkt thank you for your help. I did not imported it. I just added `import '../imports/api/users.js';` to `server/main.js` but it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I don't know why this now works but I solved it doing this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export class CollectionTable extends React.Component {

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  console.log(newProps); // i get the right data!
  console.log(this.props); // empty array >_<
}

  renderUsers() {
      return this.props.users.map(u => (
          <tr key={u._id}>
            <th scope="row">{u._id}</th>
            <td>{u.profile.firstname}</td>
            <td>{u.profile.lastname}</td>
            <td>{u.profile.phonenumber}</td>
          </tr>
          ));
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <table className="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.renderUsers()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default withTracker(() => {
  const sub = Meteor.subscribe('users');
  if (sub.ready()) {
    console.log(Meteor.users.find().fetch());
    return {
      users: Meteor.users.find().fetch()
    };
  }
  return { users: [] };
})(CollectionTable);
```

I left my console.log for debugging purposes if ever someone can explain why `this.props`gives an empty array, because it is still a mystery for me.

It works perfectly though !

Answer (score 1):

I think this occurs because it's not waiting for getting data.

Try this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('users',async function() {
        return await Meteor.users.find({});
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do it that should work is to have a callback function on the subscribe call, which will wait for it to come back with data before continuing, allowing the users to be loaded.

```
var users = Meteor.subscribe('users', function() {
  return {
    users: Meteor.users.find().fetch()
  };
});
```

And inside your withTracker (haven't tested but should work):

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  return Meteor.subscribe('users', function() {
    return {
      users: Meteor.users.find().fetch()
    };
  });
})(CollectionTable);
```

Read more: https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe